# Ширина выводимого текста WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть вариант получения ширины текста в **логических юнитах** через **GetTextExtentPoint32**, но не смог найти как перевести их в **пиксели**.

Суть вопроса **либо** найти метод **получения** сразу в **пикселях**, **либо** как перевести **логические юниты** в **пиксели**.

Comment: Использовать `LPtoDP` для перевода результата в пиксели?

Comment: Вот где ты был раньше) Большое спасибо!